# Boolean rings have characteristic $2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be a ring such that $a^2=a$ for all $a\in R$. Show that $a+a=0$ for all $a\in R$.

I don't really understand what to do here. The only way that this would be possible is if $a=0$. So $R$ would contain only $0$. But then $R$ wouldn't be a ring because it would contain an additive identity, but not a multiplicative identity. Or would it just be the zero ring and we're done?

Also, what difference would it make if $R$ was a commutative ring such that $a^2=a$. How would that change the proof of $a+a=0$ for all $a\in R$.

Comment: $a=a^2=(-a)^2=-a$

Comment: If you want to learn more, rings with $a^2=a$ for all $a$ are called Boolean rings.

Comment: So, the additive inverse exists in $R$ even if it is not specifically a commutative ring?

Answer (score 3):

Your claim that this would only be possible if $a=0$ is incorrect. In the ring $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$, we have that $1+1=0$, yet $1\neq 0$. (We also have $a^2=a$ for each $a$). As it has been written in the [comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/522126/let-r-be-a-ring-such-that-a2-a-for-all-a-in-r-show-that-aa-0-for-all#comment1116661_522126), without assuming the ring has a unit you may write $a=a^2=(-a)^2=-a$, whence $a+a=0$.

Answer (score 3):

This is known as a **boolean ring**, and a non zero example would be $1\in \mathbb{Z}_2$.

A proof:
$$0 = (a+a)^2 - (a+a) = (a^2 -a) + (a^2 - a) + a + a = a + a = 0$$
As to your point regarding commutativity, note that $R$ **must** be commutative:
$$(a+b)^2=a^2+ab+ba+b^2=(a+b)$$
$$\to\quad ab+ba=0$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$a+1=(a+1)^2=a^2+2a+1$$

What is $a^2$?

Comment: Is R unitary? if not, $1$ may not exist..

Comment: @nbubis: In that case, $a+a$ works just as well as $a+1$.

Comment: @Hurkyl - yes, that's my answer..

Answer (score 0):

an easy proof would be to use that g+g=g implies g=0  (1)

we take

a+a=(a+a)=(a+a)^2=a^2+aa+aa+a^2=a+a+a+a=(a+a)+(a+a)
=>
(a+a)=(a+a)+(a+a)
=>
a+a=0 for all a out of R because of (1)

it is as well easy to see that R musst be commutative
supposed ab=!ba are not equal
=>
aaba=!abaa
=>
aba=!aba which is an objection

so ab musst equal ba ab=ab

Comment: Welcome to the site! This looks like a nice answer, but it could really use some editing for mechanics and also proper (readable) MathJax/LaTeX formatting.